# My dropdown menu in navbar is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am creating a dropdown menu in my navigation bar but when I click on it, nothing happens. I have tried everything I could but it doesn't solve my problem.

This is what my navbar looks like:
[image]
Here my HTML code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "About", "Home")</li>
      @* 
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.DropDownList("Services","ALL")</li>
      *@ 
      <li>
         <div class="My_dropdown">
            <button class="My_dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()"> Services <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down glyph-pad"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="My_dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
               <a href="#">service1</a>
               <a href="#">service2</a>
               <a href="#">service3</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
         <a href="@Url.Action(" SignUp","Account")">
         <Span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></Span> Sign Up </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="@Url.Action(" Login","Account")">
         <Span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></Span> Login </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This is what CSS looks like:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
     color: black;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .My_dropdown:hover .My_dropbtn, .My_dropbtn:focus {
     background-color: #8080ff;
     color: white;
}
.glyph-pad {
     left: -4px;
     top: 4px;
}
.My_dropdown {
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;
}
.My_dropdown .My_dropbtn {
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 1em;
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     color: black;
     padding: 13px 12px;
     background-color: inherit;
     font-family: inherit;
    /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
     margin: 0px;
}
.My_dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     min-width: 160px;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     z-index: 1;
}
.My_dropdown-content > a {
     float: none;
     color: black;
     padding : 13px 12px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
}
.My_dropdown-content > a:hover {
     background-color: #8080ff;
}
.My_dropdown:hover .My_dropdown-content {
     display: block;
}
.show {
     display: block;
}
```

This is my JavaScript file.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.My_dropbtn')) {
        var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
        if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I rendered my scripts:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MyScripts")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance.

**Edit :**
finally I solved it. In my case I had to include the popper.min.js file to my code for dropdown to work.

Comment: You need to use the dropdown classes from bootstrap and especially [data-toggle="dropdown"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/) (no special function needed).

Comment: i did that but now my dropdown menu looks different and it is still not working.

Comment: When using bootstrap the best method is to first create the interface element you want, and make sure it works. Then you can style it either by adding styling, not by removing things, or [by using Sass](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/theming/).

Comment: u mean to say that first i have to create a dropdown button which is working and then style them?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Until you've got enough experience you need to start from working code before you try to customize the styling. If you do that you can check regularly whether it still works. Then if it doesn't you can roll back your latest changes.

Comment: also when i run that dropdown code from W3Schools in a different html file, there it worked but when i try to use same code in my project its not working. can u tell me whats causing the problem.

Comment: There can be many causes, but usually it is a problem with [the way bootstrap was included](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template). You need JQuery before bootstrap and you need the stylesheets and Javascripts. Use [the developer tools of your browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to make sure they are loaded properly. Check for [error message in the console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console).

Comment: As KIKO hinted at, you're making things very difficult for yourself. All of this dropdown stuff you are trying to code and get working properly is included as a standard part of the bootstrap nav. It really is very quick and little more than a copy paste job.

Comment: i did copy pasted the bootstrap's dropdown, which also does not shows the menu items but when I inspect them in browser and change some css properties it works there. also thanks both of u guys it helped me alot.